# Free to release an App & make money off it

Tags: mobile, appcelerator

I have a mobile app I would like to develop & sell. If I use Titanium Appcelerator to create the app, do I need to purchase a licence or subscription to sell my app because it was made with Appcelerator?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844262/appcelerator-who-uses-it See top vote

Answer (score 0):

You can devlop your app for free and to publish your  app you need to pay license fee to appcelerator.its a platform for android devlopers to devlop apps without any hassle and when they realise thats its a working well,they can publish.
Remember,appcelerator is a good way to create apps without much effort and time.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Any reference for the license and/or the process for paying fee? This would be great.